# Android Gradle: library jar flavors?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-productflavors

I need to build an Android library as a JAR (as well as an AAR), but also with flavors. The flavors happen to be based on the source compatibility.

I have this,

```
android.productFlavors {
  java6 {
    // yes, other stuff here
  }
  java7 {
    // and here
  }
}
...
task jar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

But I only get one .jar in `build/libs`. I see the build output,

```
:common-taskqueue:jarJava6Debug
:common-taskqueue:jarJava7Debug
...
```

So it seems like it's doing the work, but possibly writing each JAR to the same output file for each flavor?